# Missing Documentation on _rules

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where did this documentation move to?http://ros.org/doc/api/rospkg/html/distro_format.html#version-control-rules

[referenced here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Setup/Repository)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67233/missing-documentation-on-_rules/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can be found here: http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rospkg/html/distro_format.html#version-control-rules

I've updated the reference.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1